# CodeCollaborator + Perforce: autosubmit changelist?

Tags: automation, perforce, code-collaborator

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure CodeCollaborator to submit the changelist when the code review for it is complete? The SCM is Perforce.

Bonus points for appending the code review ID to the changelist description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file content in the pending changelist only exists on the developer's machine, so there's no way for the Code Collaborator server to submit it automatically.

However Code Collaborator does provide a "Commit Files" action item when a review of a pending changelist is complete to remind you to do the submit.  If you're running the Code Collaborator Tray Notifier then double-clicking on the "Commit Files" action item opens up a dialog that commits the changelist(s) that were in the review.

You can append the review ID to the changelist description automatically on submit by configuring the Code Collaborator "update-changelist" Perforce trigger - see here in Code Collaborator's manual: http://smartbear.com/docs/manual/5.0/ccollab_admin_trigger_update_changelist.html

Comment: I never knew that you can see the pending actions in the notifier tray. I had tried dbl-clicking and right-clicking the icon before, but never single-clicking... and there's no option to see the actions list from the GUI.